# Bind mvn jetty:run to a different phase?

Tags: maven, maven-jetty-plugin

I have a maven webapp, which can be run using jetty. If I call jetty with

```
mvn jetty:run
```

it is executed before the install phase. However, I want to run jetty at the very end of the maven lifecycle only. How can I achieve that?

Or to put it in a different way. The run goal of jetty maven plugin is bound by default to a certain maven phase. Can I change that binding?

**Update:** Just to make sure, I don't want to know how to execute jetty automatically each time a maven phase is executed like pre-integration-test. I just want to bind the jetty run goal to a later phase so that additional maven phases get executed when calling it manually.

Comment: Have you tried `mvn jetty:run-war`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible (using predefined packagings like `jar` or `war`). In Maven you run plugin's goal *or* phase (which starts lifecycle). If you run goal, only this goal is executed. If you run phase, lifecycle runs from the beginning to that phase included. Try to run (after `mvn clean`) `mvn install:install` (goal only) and then `mvn install` (default lifecycle to the `install` phase included).

You can create own plugins' goals to lifecycle's phases binding by creating own packaging type. Predefined packaging types (`jar`, `war`, `ear`, etc.) have this binding already specified.